# Replace special character with an escape preceded special character in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, data-structures, escaping

In my java code, if a string input has got any of the special characters mentioned, that should get preceded by `\\`

Special character set is `{+, -, &&, ||, !, (, ), {, },[, ], ^, "", ~, *, ?, :, \}`. I tried using `String.replaceAll(old,new)` but to my surprise its not working, even though I am giving proper values for 'old' and 'new'.

```
if old=":",new="\:"
```

I put the special chars in a String array, iterated it in a for loop, checked whether it is present in the string, if yes, `input.replaceAll(":","\\:")`. But its not giving me the intended output. Please help

```
String[] arr = { "+", "-", "&&", "||", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}",
                "[", "]", "^", "\"", "~", "*", "?", ":", "\\", "AND", "OR" };

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
//'search' is my input string

        if (search.contains((String) arr[i])) {

            String oldString = (String) arr[i];

            String newString = new String("\\" + arr[i]);
            search = search.replaceAll(oldString, newString);
            String newSearch = new String(search.replaceAll(arr[i],
                    newString));


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

Once you realise replaceAll takes a regex, it's just a matter of coding your chars as a regex.

Try this:

```
String newSearch = search.replaceAll("(?=[]\\[+&|!(){}^\"~*?:\\\\-])", "\\\\");
```

That whacky regex is a "look ahead" - a non capturing assertion that the following char match something - in this case a character class.

Notice how you don't need to escape chars in a character class, except a `]` (even the minus don't need escaping if first or last).

The `\\\\` is how you code a regex literal `\` (escape once for java, once for regex)

Here's a test of this working:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String search = "code:xy";
    String newSearch = search.replaceAll("(?=[]\\[+&|!(){}^\"~*?:\\\\-])", "\\\\");
    System.out.println(newSearch);
}
```

Output:

```
code\:xy
```

Comment: You also need to escape `[`.

Comment: @RohitJain no you don't need to escape `[`. Try it

Comment: @Bohemian.. Tried it, that's why I posted the comment. It's not working.

Comment: @RohitJain I want to see this for myself! I can't check now (using iPhone) but will check ASAP. I was sure you didn't, but I keep learning stuff here

Comment: @RohitJain                                         Thanks Bohemian and Rohit. When I used this it gave an unclosed character class exception, so [ should be escaped right?Also if any of the symbol is present in my string that should be replaced with an escape followed by that symbol itself, how to achieve that using this pattern?How to get that group value to be appended with "\\" in java. I tried for an input like a*b, but it failed. I will verify it again and will let you know

Comment: When I tried for an input string code:xy it failed giving StringIndexOutOfBoundsException at                                                              String newSearch = search.replaceAll("(?=[-+&|!(){}[\\]^\"~*?:\\\\])", "\\");            java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.appendReplacement(Matcher.java:703)
at java.util.regex.Matcher.replaceAll(Matcher.java:813)
at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:2189)

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)(?=[-+&|!(){}\\[\\]^\"~*?:\\\\])(.*)");
   Matcher m = p.matcher(search);
   String s0 = m.group(0);
   String s1 = m.group(1);
   String s2 = m.group(2);                  Now for code:xy, s0=code:xy, s1=code and s2=:xy. So I need to get like this and should append that with \\ while using replaceAll() right?

Comment: @user1863118 OK I fixed the problem. It took me a while to realise that I needed to double-escape the *replacement* backslash ie `\\\\ ` See edited answer, including some testing code to show that it *does* in fact work :)

Comment: Invalid escape sequence in JSON string '\:'

Comment: @Dean then try removing the colon `:` from the regex.

Answer (score 3):

[`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes a `regex` as first parameter. So, your code will fail if the input in the string is a `meta-character` like - `+`.

You should use [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29).

And also you don't need the last assignment: -

```
String newSearch = new String(search.replaceAll(arr[i], newString));
```

As, you are not using it at all. You are in fact assigning the modified string back to `search`, so it's not required.

Also, rather than using `new String(...)`, to build your new string.
In fact, you just need a single line in your `if-statement`.

Ok now, after that **explanation**, you can now use the below `for-loop`: -

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (search.contains(arr[i])) {
        search = search.replace(arr[i], "\\" + arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. And inorder to use replace instead of replaceAll, I have to loop over my input string,making that the outer loop and this one the inner loop right. I thought to avoid iterating the input string(thinking of cases when input string length gets large!).Also there are some symbols that cannot be escaped with a single '\' right...like for \ itself, we need to escape it as '\\\\' right?

Comment: @Rohit, am getting help from you more than 4 years, thanks for being active helper!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the below one. Please use replace method instead of ReplaceAll

search = search.replace(oldString, newString);

Answer (score 0):

when I tried the code below it worked

```
String[] arr = { "+", "-", "&&", "||", "!", "(", ")", "{", "}",
                    "[", "]", "^", "\"", "~", "*", "?", ":", "\\", "AND", "OR" };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //'search' is my input string

            if (search.contains((String) arr[i])) {

                String oldString = (String) arr[i];

                String newString = new String("\\" + arr[i]);
                search = search.replaceAll(oldString,(String) ("\\" + newString));



            }
        }
```

Comment: Try for this string - `a+b`.