# Java Regular Expression how to split special characters

Tags: java

In java Regex i want to replace all the special characters to escape sequence.how can i do.
Example ::

```
//special chars ex "dd[u]i.* " to "dd//[u//]i//.//*"
```

Comment: You might want to note that escaping is done using `\ ` (backslash) and not `/`.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13696653/2235132) might help.

Answer (score 1):

To escape all special regexp control characters this method can be used:

```
Matcher.quoteReplacement(String s)
```

It returns a regular expression that matches exact `s`.

This comes from the javadoc:

*Returns a literal replacement String for the specified String. This method produces a String that will work as a literal replacement s in the appendReplacement method of the Matcher class. The String produced will match the sequence of characters in s treated as a literal sequence. Slashes ('\') and dollar signs ('$') will be given no special meaning.*

Answer (score 0):

To split or treat special characters in java pattern as normal one. You have to backshlas it.
`\\.`; `\\*` it might be treat now as '.' and '*'.