# how to Download a XML file from a URL by Escaping Special Characters like &lt; &gt; $amp; etc?

Tags: java, xml, url, encoding

i am using this code to Download the Xml file.

```
String url="https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/16160/000001616016000061/calm-20160528.xml";

            String fileName = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                    url.length());

            String completeFileLocationWithName="/home/user/Downloads/XBRLCODE/"+fileName;

            URL surl = new URL(url);
            con = surl.openConnection();
            con.setConnectTimeout(0);
            con.setReadTimeout(0);
            InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
            Files.copy(in, Paths.get(completeFileLocationWithName));*/
```

and also tried with `String escapedInput = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(appNameInput);`

INPUT is  : URL

OUTPUT is Upon Downloading XML, it should not have above characters like `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&amp;`  etc - instead < , > ,& would be fine for me..

Please anyone share the knowledge on this..

Comment: Have you check also unescapeHtml method in StringEscapeUtils

Comment: String escapedInput = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(div);

Comment: @HRgiger tried..plz share the code

Answer (score 0):

Use **StringEscapeUtils** from **commons-lang.jar** library.

Here is working code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/16160/000001616016000061/calm-20160528.xml";

        URL surl;
        try {
            surl = new URL(url);
            URLConnection con = surl.openConnection();
            con.setConnectTimeout(0);
            con.setReadTimeout(0);
            InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            IOUtils.copy(in, writer, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(writer.toString()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Output is without escaped characters, here is sample from console:

```
<td valign="bottom" style="width:02.96%;border-top:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-left:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-bottom:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-right:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;background-color: #auto;height:1.00pt;padding:0pt;">
                    <p style="margin:0pt;font-family:Times New Roman;height:1.00pt;overflow:hidden;font-size:0pt;">
                        &nbsp;</p>
                </td>
                <td valign="bottom" style="width:02.40%;border-top:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-left:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-bottom:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-right:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;background-color: #auto;height:1.00pt;padding:0pt;">
                    <p style="margin:0pt;font-family:Times New Roman;height:1.00pt;overflow:hidden;font-size:0pt;">
                        &nbsp;</p>
                </td>
                <td valign="bottom" style="width:11.82%;border-top:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-left:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-bottom:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;border-right:1pt none #D9D9D9 ;background-color: #auto;height:1.00pt;padding:0pt;">
                    <p style="margin:0pt;font-family:Times New Roman;height:1.00pt;overflow:hidden;font-size:0pt;">
                        &nbsp;</p>
                </td>
```

Keep on mind that you need:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;
```

Comment: @JohnAdam Check update, I think this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

I think you're misunderstanding the problem slightly. Your XML here contains *embedded* HTML (itself with embedded CSS, as it happens).

To be included in that node, those characters *have* to be escaped, otherwise the overall XML would be invalid (`<`, `>`, `&` etc are all [reserved entities in XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)).

If you mean you want the results of *that XML node* (`us-gaap:FiscalPeriod`) **un**escaped, then you should extract its string value and then use something like `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml` as already suggested.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to go further and [strip all HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/remove-html-tags-from-a-string) from the output anyway.

Comment: my question is How to download a XML file without having those special characters.

Comment: Choose a different XML file? They're _already_ in there - you have to deal with them by processing your input to get the output you want.

Comment: please i  edited the code if anyone can share the code then it very helpful.... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work.

```
    InputStream iStream = new FileInputStream(new File("xxxxx"));
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    IOUtils.copy(iStream, writer, "UTF-8");
    String theString = writer.toString();
    IOUtils.write(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(theString),
            new FileOutputStream("yyyy"));
```

Comment: its working fine but &nbsp; is the problem in "yyyy" file... do you have any other solution to overcome.

Comment: ï»¿ this special character i am getting while doing this in HTML

Comment: ï»¿ got solution for this character in HTML.... <meta charset=\"UTF-8\">