# Why my replaceAll not work

Tags: java, string, special-characters, replaceall

I try to remove special characters from string but the point is only "?" still on the output string while the others was removed properly.

```
String[] special = {"\\*",";","_","=", "\\[", "\\]", ":", "\\?", "-", "\\.", 
"\\)", "\\(", "/", "!", "#", ",", "\"", "“", "”"};
    for (int i = 0; i < special.length; i++) {
        source = source.replaceAll(special[i], "");
    }
```

this is my string

https://file.io/JjiLhD

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696461/replace-special-character-with-an-escape-preceded-special-character-in-java) SO question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace special character with an escape preceded special character in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13696461/replace-special-character-with-an-escape-preceded-special-character-in-java)

Comment: I knows it's duplicate I know how replace work but I just wanna know why question mark still appear on my text why others was replaced properly

Comment: Because you are viewing it as improperly encoded string

Comment: You should make that *much* clearer in your question then - at the moment, your question *reads* as if you're asking how to do the replacement properly, rather than satisfying your curiosity about why it's not working with `replaceAll`. If it's just the latter, I'm sure you can provide a simpler [mcve] than your current question.

Answer (score 4):

You should use `replace` instead of `replaceAll` because `replaceAll` uses input regex

```
for (int i = 0; i < special.length; i++) {
        source = source.replace(special[i], "");
    }
```

`replace` is same function with `replaceAll` but different input

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
>   sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence.

Comment: thanks for the answer but when i use replace it will do 1 time but replaceAll replace all of my context there's still "?" appears :(

Comment: No, `replace` did replaceAll task, you can try it,  It is java naming issue, you can read javadoc about it

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `alphanumeric` characters.

```
.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", ""));
```

and only `alphabetical` characters,

```
.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", ""));
```